# Python turtle circle function

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics

So I'm reading a book to learn python and I got to a part about the module turtle.
So after explaining it, it gives you some exercises.
One of them is to define a function that creates regular polygons.
I got this to work.

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()

def polygon(t, l, n): 
    angle = 360/n
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(l)
        t.lt(angle)
polygon(bob, 40, 5)
```

For example this draws a regular pentagon.

The next exercise asks you to draw a "circle" changing the number of sides of the polygon.
The problem is that sometimes it doesn't work and the polygon/circle doesn't close.
I tried to find the solution by changing lots of time both the lenght and the number of sides or only one of the two but I didn't succeed.
For example, lenght = 10 and n°sides = 140 doesn't work, instead lenght = 20 and n°sides = 120 works.

Can someone explain, please?

Found solution.
Being a beginner I forgot about integers and floats.
That's why the "circle" wasn't closing.

Comment: Surely a circle when defined in `sides`, that is not equal to one, must have at most and at a minimum 360. One for each degree. Also, width and height must be equal as the radii of a circle is constant.

Comment: In fact the polygons drawn are regular but in some cases they don't close. I'm not trying to draw a circle but a polygon that looks like a circle, human eyes can't zoom so regular polygons with many sides looks like circles to us. I don't understand why sometimes the polygons don't close, can you be more specific, please? For example you said "at most and at a minumum 360", 360 what?

Comment: Can you clarify `close`, do you mean the shape vertices not joining with the starting edge (but is aligned on the circumferential path), or that the edge angles are disproportionate; to clarify, `edge angle != edges / 360`? What I meant was that a circle, non polygon, has a circumference that elopes a 360 degree radial space. Surely any polygon, whether to the human eye indistinguishable compared to a circle, or one that was large enough to distinguish the edge angle between vertices, must have an exterior angle of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in Python 3 but didn't close the polygon in Python 2 due to the difference in how division works.  The fix is to simply use 360.0 instead of 360 and then it works fine in both:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def polygon(t, l, n):
    angle = 360.0 / n

    for _ in range(n):
        t.fd(l)
        t.lt(angle)

bob = Turtle()

polygon(bob, 10, 140)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Python turtle's own `circle()` method actually draws polygons with the default assumption that 60 sides is sufficient to look like a circle on the screen.  Unless the circle is very small (then it uses fewer sides) or the user insists on more (or less) sides via the `steps` argument.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out later. I was following a Python 3 guide while using Python 2. After I found the solution I went on reading and it said that too in the guide. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting 360.0 instead of 360, because the initial value of Python is in integers.
We want to convert it into decimals, that's why we put the .0 after the 360.